# Symfony2 validation and bootstrap/jquery modal

Tags: jquery, symfony, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following situation:

I rendered a symfony2-form into a modal (using bootstrap and jQuery). When the form is not valid, the error message should appear inside the modal box. I linked to the modal box like this: route/to/action#modal

How can I do that?

In my template, I have a simple link to a modal:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#new">Add member</a>
```

This link opens a modal. Inside, there is a simple form with title, first_name and last_name:

```
{{ form_widget(form.title) }}
{{ form_widget(form.first_name) }}
{{ form_widget(form.last_name) }}
```

In the form class, I defined it like this:

```
 $builder
        ->add('title', 'text', array('required' => false))
        ->add('first_name')
        ->add('last_name');
```

So, the title is optional and the first- and lastname are required. So I added those lines into my validation.yml:

```
Acme\MemberBundle\Entity\Member:
properties:
    first_name:
        - NotBlank: { message: Please enter a first name }
    last_name:
        - NotBlank: { message: Please enter a last name }
```

And in my action (that is called when the form is submitted) I have the following lines:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Member entity.
 *
 * @Route("/create", name="acme_member_create")
 * @Method("post")
 * @Template("AcmeMemberBundle:Member:index.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction()
{
    $member = new Member();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form = $this->createForm(new MemberType(), $member);
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($member);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_member'));

    }

    $entities = $em->getRepository('AcmeMemberBundle:Member')->findAll();

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

So, when the for is not valid, I want to route back to my index.html.twig (where the modal is displayed).

Comment: I tried it with a simple validation.yml and error-messages. But when I route back to my template, the modal box disappears.

Comment: I want to see a bit of code! We not code for you but we can help you to get your code working

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

With this JavaScript-Code, I can show the modal when the page is loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#new').modal()
});
```

So, I just execute this code if the form is not valid.